# JsonIOException: Interfaces can't be instantiated! Register an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type. Interface name: retrofit2.Call

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am making a post-call with username and password parameters. The actual call is working and the HTTP response is successful but the following error is being returned.

Error

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Interfaces can't be instantiated! Register an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type. Interface name: retrofit2.Call
    W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:136)
    W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$FieldReflectionAdapter.createAccumulator(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:427)
    W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:383)
    W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
    W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
    W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
    W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
    W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
```

Service

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    suspend fun authenticateUser(@Field("email") email: String, @Field("password") password: String): Call<LoginResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

###### Replace `Call` with `Response`

---

#### Details

You are here mixing suspend-style and `Call`-based usages of Retrofit:

- If you want benefit from using a suspend method (hint: you do), the return type of `authenticateUser` should be `Response<LoginResponse>` not `Call<LoginResponse>`:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    suspend fun authenticateUser(@Field("email") email: String, @Field("password") password: String): Response<LoginResponse>
```

- If you want to use Retrofit's `Call`, you should make it not suspendable and use `Call::enqueue` (for asynchronous call) or `Call::execute` (for synchronous call):

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    fun authenticateUser(@Field("email") email: String, @Field("password") password: String): Call<LoginResponse>
    
    ...
    // Somewhere

    //This
    val loginResponse = authenticateUser("email", "password).execute() // throws IOException upon problem talking to the server

    // Or this
    authenticateUser("email", "password).enqueue(object:Callback<LoginResponse>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
            // It worked!
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            // Something went wrong
        }
    })
```

#### See

- [Retrofit's version 2.6.0 changelog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05) (introduces `suspend` support)
- [Retrofit's webpage](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Retrofit's javadoc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/)